# json_encoding an array but comes out as a string

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

im trying to do an ajax call to a php file which will then make an array, encode it to json and then console.log the first item in the array. At the moment i have this on my homepage :

```
<script>                

window.setInterval(function ajaxcall(){
            $.ajax({url: "functions/displayPostsDynamic.php",
                success: function(data) 
                {
                console.log(data[0]);
                }
            });
        }, 1000);
</script>
```

So every second it will call functions/displayPostsDynamic.php and then output the first item when it receives the data.

This is the php page that its calling:

```
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$responseArray = [];

if ($count > 0) //If there is more than one post
{   
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) //For every post, display each one
    { 
        $currentPost[] = ['post_id' => $row["post_id"],'user_id' => $row["user_id"], 'post' => $row["post"], 'date' => $row["date"],'votes_down' => $row["votes_down"],
        'votes_up' => $row["votes_up"]];
    }
    array_push($responseArray, $currentPost);
}   

$stmt->close(); //Close the statment and connection
$conn->close();

echo json_encode(array($responseArray));
?>
```

So above all this it makes a connection to a sql database and $count is how many entrys in a table. So for each entry i want to add all the details to an array and at the end, push every entry to 1 big array so it can be transfered back to the homepage. So if i print out the responseArray just before it gets sent, it will print out this:

```
 Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
            [post_id] => 117 
            [user_id] => 59 
            [post] => lol 
            [date] => 2017-03-26 18:36:21 
            [votes_down] => 2 
            [votes_up] => 1 
        ) 
        [1] => Array ( 
            [post_id] => 104 
            [user_id] => 46 
            [post] => hi from player8 
            [date] => 2017-03-23 22:19:10 
            [votes_down] => 19 
            [votes_up] => 17 
        ) 
    ) 
)
```

There is only 2 entries in the table so that works just fine. Back to the homepage when it runs the console prints out `[` as its the first character of the string thats being received instead of the first item of the array. Would anybody know how to transfer an array or even convert the string to an array when it gets back to the homepage? thanks for any help

Comment: Please don't vandalize your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this right before echoing:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($responseArray);
```

What i notice in your code in case your wondering that your data is strangely filled with deep arrays.

```
$responseArray = []; // initialize array
if ($count > 0) //If there is more than one post
{
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) //For every post, display each one
    {
        $currentPost = ['post_id' => $row["post_id"],'user_id' => $row["user_id"], 'post' => $row["post"], 'date' => $row["date"],'votes_down' => $row["votes_down"],
            'votes_up' => $row["votes_up"]];
        array_push($responseArray, $currentPost); // probably just want to add the post not initialize an array and put the post into that
    }
}

$conn->close();

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($responseArray); // probably dont need that array init here either
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data are processed like string, you just need to set data type in your jquery ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "functions/displayPostsDynamic.php",
   dataType: "json",
```

or you can use JSON.parse:

```
success: function(data) 
{
   data = JSON.parse(data);
   console.log(data[0]);
}
```